# Is there a way to preserve line breaks and indentation in ACE Editor?

Tags: php, javascript, ace-editor

I am using ace editor to insert some code into a text area which is then inserted into our database.

When we do an `htmlentities()` on the resulting code, it all appears in one line.
We would like to wrap the code in `<pre>` tags so that we can display it on a web page in  a nice easy to read format.

Thank you!

Comment: this question is unclear, Is ace related to the problem, except for being used before textarea. If you want to wrap code in pre tags what stops you from doing it?

Comment: I want to basically move the ace formatted code to the database and preserve the formatting

Comment: In that case you need to split up the question. 
You can get ace contents trivially with `text = editor.getValue()` and set with `editor.setValue(text)` after which you can just handle it the usual way. So i think this isn't a question about ace and ace-editor tag should be removed.